# Two orthogonal circles problem

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, tangent-line

Two circles $Ω_1$and $Ω_2$ with centers $Ο_1$  and $Ο_2$ respectively, intersect each other at points $C$ and $D$.

Two tangents $λ_1$ and $λ_2$ are drawn at point $C$, perpendicular to each other, cutting $Ω_1$ at point $A$ and $Ω_2$ at point $B$ respectively.

Points $Ο_1$and $Ο_2$ are joined, thus intersecting $Ω_1$ and $Ω_2$ at points $X$ and $Y$ respectively.

Furthermore, lines $AX$ and $BY$ are drawn which intersect each other at point $G$.

Find the measure of $∠GCA$

I could get the figure correctly but I could not go ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construct $AB.$
We know that $\frac{CO_{1}}{O_{1}A}=\frac{CO_{2}}{O_{2}B}=1.$

By converse of Thales Theorem, 
$AB||O_{1}O_{2}$

So, 
$∠AXO_1=∠XAB$                                       ........$(1)$

We know that
$AO_1=O_{1}X$

So, $∠AXO_1=∠O_{1}AX$                             ......$(2)$.

From $(1)$ and $(2),$     $AX$ is the angular bisector of $∠O_{1}AB.$

Similarly,  $BY$ is the angular bisector of $∠O_{2}BA$

Hence, $G$ is the incenter of $ΔABC.$

Thus, $CG$ also bisects $∠ACB.$

Finally, $$∠GCA=\frac{90°}{2}=45°=\frac{π}{4}radians.$$
Ans.

Comment: How does $AX$ bisect angle $O_1 AB?$

Comment: @T'Challa_____See edit

Comment: Oh! Very nice proof...thank you very much....